# User Defined Type are throwing not found exception, if even the types and tables are present in cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-types

Project Type - Multi Module Project 
Database - Cassandra 
Keyspaces - 2 Creations

Query: 
         
I am trying to create all tables & user defined types using CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS property & there is custom cassandra configuration where we load two keyspaces.

On load, we are trying to create default record, but the problem is with user defined type. It keeps saying "**MappingException** : **User Type [] not exists**" but in database both user defined type & its associated table is present

Comment: Sorry, but there's not enough information here to help you.  Can you post the CQL that you're trying to run?  Also, what does "on load" mean?  Are you trying to do a COPY from within CQLSH?  Or is the CQL running from within a program or app?

Comment: Actually, on @PostConstrcut, i am creating default record. but i keep getting error message.